# Querying SQL Set

Tags: mysql, sql, set

I have an SQL field defined as `set('nightlife', 'food', 'sports', 'culture', 'movies', 'general')`

Now I want to run a query where I pass for example `nightlife,food` and I want the result to contain ALL records where the Category contains nightlife or food. So for example a record with `nightlife,culture,sports` should also be returned as it contains nightlife. I'm not sure how to run this. I tried using the `IN` keyword in the following way:

`'SELECT ... FROM table WHERE '$category' IN Categories`
however this isn't working.

UPDATE

Running following query as suggested in answer:

```html
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE id =  '2650225'
AND WHERE FIND_IN_SET('sports', Categories ) >0
OR FIND_IN_SET('nightlife', Categories ) >0
ORDER BY delete_at ASC 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

receiving following error :

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE find_in_set('sports', Categories) > 0 or find_in_set('nightlife', Categori' at line 1
```

Comment: One option is to use `find_in_set('nightlife', categories)>0 or find_in_set('food', categories)>0`.  You cannot search for multiple values at the same time -- you'll need to use `or`.

Comment: Ok so if I search for 'nightlife' in 'nightlife,food' would this work or do I have to search for 'nightlife,food' for it to match?

Comment: I think you need to use `find_in_set` or `like` -- I don't think `in` will work when searching sets.

Comment: Can you post an example of an SQL query please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` with `or`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where find_in_set('nightlife', categories) > 0 or
      find_in_set('food', categories) > 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef997/1)

---

Based on your edits, you can't have multiple `where` clauses.  Also you need to use parentheses around the `or` criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE id =  '2650225' AND
    (FIND_IN_SET('sports', Categories ) > 0 OR
     FIND_IN_SET('nightlife', Categories ) >0)
ORDER BY delete_at ASC 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: @mankee -- Also you need to use parentheses around the `or` criteria.